# Where is the table for determining how many feats a character has based on level in the Pathfinder Core Rulebook?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, character-advancement, character-levels

I've paged through my entire book, looked in the index, checked the sections on feats and ability scores, and I've not been able to find the table that breaks down when you get ability score increases, and feats.

I already know that you get an ability score increase every 4th level so that's not a problem, but switching over from 3.5 to Pathfinder I know for a fact that the feat structure is different, I just don't remember how because I haven't played in a long time.

I've even looked in the Feats and Character Creation section of d20pfsrd. I cannot find this table for the life of me.

Where is this table I'm looking for located in the book, or on an online resource?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if this is the table you are looking for, but table 3-1:Character Advancement and Level-Dependent Bonuses' last two columns, Feats and Ability Score shows which levels you get an extra feat or ability score on. You get one feat at level 1 (subject to changes from race, class, etc.) and extra feats on 3rd level, 5th level, 7th level, and so on so forth.

You can find the table [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/) on d20srd and it's on page 30 in the rulebook.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yep that's the one I was looking for. I couldn't figure out where they put it. D&D 3.5 had it in the very beginning of the book but I couldn't seem to find it in Pathfinder.